# Usar Insert ou Delete utilizando SQLI PREPARE com array

Tags: php, array

No método antigo eu utilizava muito esse jeito a baixo para inserir ou deletar um linhas em serie vindo de um array. nota-se que as variáveis ficam dentro de conchetes {$x}  já utilizando o método PREPARE msqli não consigo fazer funcionar

```
  exemplo
  $query = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO user
  (nome,tel,email)VALUES('{$nome}','{$tel}',{$email}')", $conexao) or die( mysql_error());
```

ou

```
   if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
   foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $id) {

   $del = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = '{$id}' LIMIT 1";
   $resultado2 = mysql_query($del) or die ("Falha ao Excluir Registro Os"); }}
```

Como fazer esse delete por exemplo funcionar

```
  if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $valor) {
  // aqui você faz a parte da exclusão      

 $bd = new MySQLiConnection();          
 $stmt = $bd->prepare("DELETE FROM incluidos2 WHERE id=? ");
 $stmt->bind_param('i', $valor);
 $stmt->execute(); 
 $stmt->close();
 }}
```

Comment: Se passar assim já deve funcionar: `$stmt->bind_param('i', $valor);`

Comment: isso ai foi mole meu na hora de colocar aqui mais independente disso não funciona

Comment: Veja se assim exibe algum erro: `if(!$stmt->execute()){ print_r($bd->error);}`